# Django Cassandra Map field

Tags: django, cassandra, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use Django cassandra to build restful server. In my DjangoCassandraModel I want to create a columns.Map field. However, as per my understanding, DjangoCassandraModelSerializer does not support Map field.

As I request a url which uses the serializer, it raises the following error for the Map field.

```
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:   'Class Map not found in lookup.'
Exception Location:     /home/saikat/.conda/envs/django-nonrel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/field_mapping.py in __getitem__, line 40
```

Is there any workaround to use map field for Django Cassandra serializer?

The following is my model snippet.

```
class ShopProfileModel(DjangoCassandraModel):
    shop_id = columns.Ascii(required=True, index=True)
    owner = columns.Ascii(required=True, index=True)
    shop_name = columns.Text(required=True, index=True)
    shop_details = columns.Map(required=False)
```

The Serilizer field is below.

```
class ShopSerializer(DjangoCassandraModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ShopProfileModel
    fields = ('shop_id', 'shop_name', 'owner', 'shop_details')
```